How to set up authentication to Directus in a ssr nuxt app
I'm trying to authenticate to Directus in my nuxt app with the directus sdk.
I cant get the cookies to be set properly.
nuxt app: app.netlify.app (also localhost for developement)
directus: admin.myserver.com
in Directus I have this configuration:
REFRESH_TOKEN_COOKIE_DOMAIN=admin.myserver.com
REFRESH_TOKEN_COOKIE_SECURE=true
REFRESH_TOKEN_COOKIE_SAME_SITE=none
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN=admin.myserver.com
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=true
SESSION_COOKIE_SAME_SITE=none

in nuxt with ssr=true:
const directus = createDirectus('https://admin.myserver.com')
    .with(rest({ credentials: 'include' }))
    .with(authentication('session', { credentials: 'include' }));


async function userLogin() {
    try {
        const response = await directus.login('username', 'password');

        return response;

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

On chrome, a session cookie is set, but doest stick around after a page refresh.
On firefox no cookie is created.
Is SSR creating problems?  Is my config ok ?
Should I use 'json' mode in the directus sdk and handle the cookise manually ?
Should I use a proxy module in nuxt ? Should I create nuxt apis in /server so all my call are made to the same url and cookies are from the same site ?
Please help me figure out the best solution.  I've read the docs but the Directus doc is a mess and the nuxt doc is often super vague.
So, if you refer me to them, please provide a precise subject/solution.
I'm very lost, it's the fifth day I spend trying to figure this out.
Thanks !

The SDK allows one of 'session', 'cookie', 'json'. You are attempting to use 'session' but expecting a cookie to be set. I would recommend changing your authentication to .with(authentication('cookie', { credentials: 'include' }))
Documentation Reference:
https://docs.directus.io/guides/sdk/authentication.html#cross-domain-cookies
